# Help with custom widget options! (saving checkbox option)

Tags: widgets

I created a custom Flickr Widget for Wordpress and successfully set up an options form for users to enter their Flickr information, but I cannot get the checkbox in the form to save whether or not it is checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here are my widget(), form(), and update() functions:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
extract($args);

$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
$displaynum = $instance['displaynum'];
$flickrid = $instance['flickrname'];
$num = 6;
$feed = new SimplePie($instance['feed']);
$feed->handle_content_type(); 
$photostream = $instance['show_photostream'];


function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = $old_instance;

$instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title'] );
$instance['displaynum'] = strip_tags($new_instance['displaynum'] );
$instance['feed'] = $new_instance['feed'];
$instance['flickrname'] = $new_instance['flickrname'];
$instance['show_photostream'] = (bool) $new_instance['show_photostream'];

return $instance;
}

function form($instance) {
$defaults = array (
    'title' => 'My Recent Flickr Uploads',
    'displaynum' => 6,
    'feed' => 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=33927859@N06&lang=en-us&format=rss_200',
    'flickrname' => 'rastajellyfish',
    'show_photostream' => isset( $instance['show_photostream'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_photostream'] : false
);
$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    ...

    $instance['show_photostream'] = $new_instance['show_photostream'];

    return $instance;
}

function form($instance) {
    $defaults = array (
        ...
        'show_photostream' => !empty( $instance['show_photostream'] ) ? $instance['show_photostream'] : false
    );
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);
```

Comment: hmmm...there seems to still be a problem. I'll still check the checkbox in the widgets page, the save process works fine, but the value of the checkbox is not retained and always reverts to being unchecked.

Comment: can you post all the widget code? especially all the form function